# How to have flashlight toggle on sharp shake motion with Tasker?

Tags: tasker, android-12, flashlight

I would like to toggle the flashlight when shaking the phone sharply.

I have tried setting the Tasker profile to `shake left-right + display state on + not proximity sensor`. This still is very buggy. For example, while riding on the bus and using my phone the flashlight continuously turns on and off.

Any better ideas? Is there a way to make it two shakes, back to back?